# cocos2d application crashes at onEnter functiion

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

my cocos 2d application crashes at the onEnter function +[Setting onEnter]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x104558', also my app crashes at +[HighScores onEnter]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x104558'

Comment: Where is the code ?! How can we help you without seeing the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that calling a class method instead of an instance method (because onEnter is an instance method) cause the crash.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your setting and highscores does not have the function called onEnter..

Answer (score 0):

In my CCNode class , it has that function , I think it can't access that function

Comment: ... can  you reply as comment instead... zz..
did you declare it public in your settings.h?